# 3D Card Flip: CSS scaling while maintaing image clarity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Problem

I fully understand that I cannot take a downsized image, scale it up with CSS, and not have it look blurry.  But I also know I'm going about this wrong, and there ***is*** a way to do what I'm wanting.

I want to achieve this exact effect I've created, but without losing the clarity on the second (flipped / backside) card.  I feel like the solution lies somewhere with the initial width/height of the backside card and transform origins, but I can't quite get it there.  What am I doing wrong?

### Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/a9dpc05t/1/

### HTML

```
<div class="cardWrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardFace front"><img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/hearts.png" width="129"></div>
    <div class="cardFace back"><img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/spades.png" width="129"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin:50px 150px;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cardWrapper{
  width:129px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.cardFace{
  position:absolute;
  width:129px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
TweenLite.set(".cardWrapper", {
  perspective: 800
});
TweenLite.set(".card", {
  transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
});
TweenLite.set(".back", {
  rotationY: -180
});
TweenLite.set([".back", ".front"], {
  backfaceVisibility: "hidden"
});

$(".cardWrapper").click(
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 1.2, {
      rotationY: 180,
      scale: 2.48,
      ease: Back.easeOut
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT V2:**

Here's another version trying to fix what you specified in the comment.

[**jsFiddle Version 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/wqws3Lcm/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET V2:**

```js
TweenLite.set(".cardWrapper", {
  perspective: 800
});
TweenLite.set(".card", {
  transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
});
TweenLite.set(".back", {
  rotationY: -180
});
TweenLite.set([".back", ".front"], {
  backfaceVisibility: "hidden"
});

$(".cardWrapper").click(
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 1.2, {
      rotationY: 180,
      scale: 1,
      ease: Back.easeOut
    });
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 120px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.cardWrapper {
  width: 387px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cardFace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 387px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cardFace img {
  width: 387px;
}
.card {
  transform: scale(0.248);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="cardWrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardFace front">
      <img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/hearts.png">
    </div>
    <div class="cardFace back">
      <img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/spades.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cardWrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardFace front">
      <img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/hearts.png">
    </div>
    <div class="cardFace back">
      <img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/spades.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**V1:**

The trick is to initially scale the card down, then just apply the scale to 1 on flip.

---

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/woojsjn0/)**

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
TweenLite.set(".cardWrapper", {
  perspective: 800
});
TweenLite.set(".card", {
  transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
});
TweenLite.set(".back", {
  rotationY: -180
});
TweenLite.set([".back", ".front"], {
  backfaceVisibility: "hidden"
});

$(".cardWrapper").click(
  function() {
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".card"), 1.2, {
      rotationY: 180,
      scale: 1,
      ease: Back.easeOut
    });
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 120px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.cardWrapper {
  width: 144px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cardFace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 432px;
  height: 660px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cardFace img {
  width: 432px;
}
.card {
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: scale(0.248);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="cardWrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardFace front">
      <img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/hearts.png">
    </div>
    <div class="cardFace back">
      <img src="http://www.gannon.tv/cp_assets/3dplayingcardflip/images/spades.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seems really close, but the transform origin still seems off.  In my example, it stays centered as it scales up.  In yours, it swings down and to the left.  Do you know what the issue there is?

Comment: I have added another demo for you to check it out and see if that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add margin and padding to the div. Also check for the proper size of the divs in the CSS.
For the best layout, margin should be added to .card and padding should be added to .front and .back

I also made a flipping cards layout. Check this out, it may help you. :)
http://codepen.io/aman_d1996/pen/WxJwoo

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cards</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="row" style="margin:3px;">
            <div class="col-xs-3" id="card1" style="padding-bottom: 16.7vw;">
                <div class="front" style="border-top: 3px solid #e67e22;
    background: rgba(230, 126, 34, .9);">
                    <h4>TILE1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="back" style="background: rgb(65, 72, 65);">
                    <h4>BACK</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" id="card2" style="padding-bottom: 16.7vw;">
                <div class="front" style="border-top: 3px solid #ffc72c;
    background-color: rgba(255, 199, 44, 0.901961);">
                    <h4>TILE2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="back" style="background: rgb(65, 72, 65);">
                    <h4>BACK</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" id="card3" style="padding-bottom: 16.7vw;">
                <div class="front" style="border-top: 3px solid #c98bdb;
    background: rgba(201, 139, 219, .9);">
                    <h4>TILE3</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="back" style="background: rgb(65, 72, 65);">
                    <h4>BACK</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin:3px">
            <div class="col-xs-6" id="card4" style="padding-bottom: 16.7vw;">
                <div class="front" style="border-top: 3px solid #c98bdb;
    background: rgba(201, 139, 219, .9);">
                    <h4>TILE4</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="back" style="background: rgb(65, 72, 65);">
                    <h4>BACK</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" id="card5" style="padding-bottom: 16.7vw;">
                <div class="front" style="border-top: 3px solid #ffc72c;
    background-color: rgba(255, 199, 44, 0.901961);">
                    <h4>TILE5</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="back" style="background: rgb(65, 72, 65);">
                    <h4>BACK</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3" id="card6" style="padding-bottom: 16.7vw;">
                <div class="front" style="border-top: 3px solid #e67e22;
    background: rgba(230, 126, 34, .9);">
                    <h4>TILE6</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="back" style="background: rgb(65, 72, 65);">
                    <h4>BACK</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body>div>div>div>div>h4 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: 12px;
    color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function($) {
    $("#card1").flip({
        axis: 'y',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
    $("#card1").on('click', function(){
        $("#card2").flip(false);
        $("#card3").flip(false);
        $("#card4").flip(false);
        $("#card5").flip(false);
        $("#card6").flip(false);
    });
    $("#card2").flip({
        axis: 'y',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
    $("#card2").on('click', function(){
        $("#card1").flip(false);
        $("#card3").flip(false);
        $("#card4").flip(false);
        $("#card5").flip(false);
        $("#card6").flip(false);
    });
    $("#card3").flip({
        axis: 'x',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
    $("#card3").on('click', function(){
        $("#card2").flip(false);
        $("#card1").flip(false);
        $("#card4").flip(false);
        $("#card5").flip(false);
        $("#card6").flip(false);
    });
    $("#card4").flip({
        axis: 'x',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
    $("#card4").on('click', function(){
        $("#card2").flip(false);
        $("#card3").flip(false);
        $("#card1").flip(false);
        $("#card5").flip(false);
        $("#card6").flip(false);
    });
    $("#card5").flip({
        axis: 'y',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
    $("#card5").on('click', function(){
        $("#card2").flip(false);
        $("#card3").flip(false);
        $("#card4").flip(false);
        $("#card1").flip(false);
        $("#card6").flip(false);
    });
    $("#card6").flip({
        axis: 'y',
        trigger: 'click'
    });
    $("#card6").on('click', function(){
        $("#card2").flip(false);
        $("#card3").flip(false);
        $("#card4").flip(false);
        $("#card5").flip(false);
        $("#card1").flip(false);
    });
});
```